# PyQt Modeless Dialog won't show

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'd like to show a popup dialog while waiting for a message to be received by another process. I do not want this to block the code, thus using `.exec_()` appears less than ideal. When I call show `.show()` instead, the dialog never pops up at all. Interestingly it will show if I use a debugger right before it is called but still shows nothing if I sleep/wait for some time right after it. Here is my PyQt code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel


class Main(QApplication):
   def __init__(self, *args):
       super().__init__([])
       self.popup = Popup()

   def show_popup(self, msg):
       self.popup.set_msg(msg)
       self.popup.show()


class Popup(QDialog):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.label = QLabel(self)

   def set_msg(self, msg):
       self.label.setText(msg)
```

In the process from which I'm calling this I basically instantiate the `Main` Object and call `show_popup` after sending a message, waiting to change text and close upon getting a response. Using `exec_()` shows the popup but it blocks code from running in the other process. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Popup(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
   super().__init__()
   self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.Tool |Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

   self.label = QLabel(self)

def set_msg(self, msg):
   self.label.setText(msg)
```

I had problems with QMessageBox and QWidget but inherit from QMainWindows and it works as I needed.

Comment: What is the purpose of  the line that begins with `setWindowFlags`? Obviously you are setting some flags on the window but why are you piping Qt.Tool and the others? I tried inheriting from QMainWindow and the popup still doesn't show...I can only see it with exec_().

Comment: Also how did you import Qt.Tool and the others? From PyQt5 import Qt I can't find those modules...

Comment: "from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt" <<--- this
this contains the flags.
Those flags are used for:
Hide title bar and rise up that window over the others.

Comment: Still doesn't work...is it even possible to create a PyQt window without calling exec at all? Pretty much every example I've seen it looks like `exec_()` is called somewhere. If that's the case, it seems like it wouldn't be possible to create a popup and have the code run unless that code was being run from the GUI process itself.

Comment: Maybe using QMessageBox?
It uses exec() and never has failed to me.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm